# TFS Connection wont connect on lan connection without initiating a ping

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am able to connect the tfs in an wink when my pc is connected to the wifi ..
But when the lan cable is connected & wifi is off it does not connect .. until ..i ping the tfs through my PC .. 2 or 3 drops , it starts pinging and i am able to connect to the tfs .. When i diagnose the connection (inbuit windows function) it shows the error "your computer appears to be correctly configured but the device or resource (dns server) is not responding" .. I did all the steps ( flush , register , relealse , renew ) but the error wont go .. I did this because i thought that may be the problem causing error .. (is it?)

My internet works fine , when tfs is not connected & also when its connected ..

Comment: Did you connect TFS from Visual Studio/Team Explorer or from web portal? If you connected from Visual Studio/Team Explorer, how about connecting from web portal when this issue happened?

Comment: i was connecting through VS 2010 ..
however i realised this was happening due to a wifi router on the floor ..
when i switched off the router , the ping & connection were perfeect .. now on replacing the router with a new one no problems with the conenction .. 


just for the record , if someone else faces this problem , try changing ports in the switch ..and switching off the routers/access points ..

Thanks Cece for the concern !!

Comment: @Anush Chouthai, Since this  issue has been resolved, would you please add your solution as an answer, and then mark it, so it could help other community members who get the same issue find the solution easily. Thanks for your sharing again.